# Abundance influenced by stress factors - which model and how to analyse it?

Tags: r, mixed-model, experiment-design

I would like to ask for your help regarding my data. I would like to know how best to model it and what analysis I should use. The mesocosm experiment was conducted in a full factorial design. We had 2 levels per variable (stressors).

My table looks somewhat like this:

**mesocosm      taxa            abundance   stressor1    stressor2     stressor3**

1             taxa1           30          yes          yes           yes

1             taxa2           46          yes          no            no

1             taxa3           12          yes          ...

1             taxa4           3           yes

2             taxa1           32          no

2             taxa2           50          no

2             taxa3           8           no

2             taxa4           10          no

3             ...

So far I have used:

```r
model <- glmer(abundance ~ stressor1 * stressor2 * stressor3 * taxa + 
               (1|mesocosm), family = poisson, data=df) 

EMM <- emmeans(model, ~ stressor1 * stressor2 * stressor3 * taxa, 
               adjust = "fdr")

pairs(EMM, simple = "stressor1")
```

Now I am wondering which might be more appropriate: glm or glmer, anova or emmeans. If I use glm/anova, do I have to use deviation coding. Furthermore, what do I do if I only want to look at one variable (e.g. control vs. stressor1) and segregate the data relating to it? Can I continue to use the model after removing the two superfluous variables, or do I need to use a different model? I would appreciate any advice or clarification.

Comment: Can you explain what is *mesocosm*? Please do so as an edit to the post, and then tell us some more of the context. This has not gotten much attention, probably because it contains to little info an an informed answer!